# Notation question: $SL(2,3)$, $SL_2(F_3)$, and $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, finite-fields, linear-groups

Do this all notation equivalent?
$SL(2,3)$, $SL_2(F_3)$, and $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$

I am new to the topic and want to know whether above expressions are same.

Comment: Yes, I think they're the same.

Comment: Usually the field with three elements is denoted by $\Bbb F_3$ (and not by $F_3$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all notations are the same.

The general form of the second and third variant is $\operatorname{SL}_n(R)$, denoting the group of all $n\times n$ matrices over $R$ of determinant $1$ ("special linear group").
Since the two rings $F_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ are isomorphic (field of order $3$), both variants denote the same thing.

The general form of the first version is $\operatorname{SL}(n,q)$, which serves as an abbreviation for $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$.